# Is it possible to convert apk file to IPA file?

Tags: android, iphone

Is it possible to convert apk file produced for Android to ipa file for Iphone?

Comment: Nope, not at all. Apk is different from ipa architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be transformed, but you can generate it from ionic, since ionic is a hybrid platform, therefore you can generate from there a version for android and another for iOS.

You can see a way
[here](https://medium.com/@vicmarcal/ionic-compile-and-upload-an-ios-app-avoiding-most-of-the-pitfalls-72632309b943)

Answer (score 1):

Android apk can't be converted to iOS ipa. Only possibility is either you devlop cross platform(xamrin/react native/ionic/flutter) app project which can share common code and some android/ios platform specific code.

Answer (score 1):

***In short, the answer is No.***

APK and IPA are extensions that will serve different platforms and their architecture won't be the same, too.

You can try hybrid app development to add platforms: android and ios at the same time.
Example: Flutter, React Native, Ionic, Cordova